# Custom render texture проблема с шейдером

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

Я делаю простою рисовалку с помощью кастомной текстуры. Код частично не мой. Моя проблема заключается в том что я не правильно возращаю цвет пикселя(см картинка). Я думаю это проблема в лерпе, но я не знаю как исправить. Есть идеи?

```
            float4 frag(v2f_customrendertexture IN) : COLOR
            {
                float4 previousColor = tex2D(_SelfTexture2D, IN.localTexcoord.xy);
                float2 pos = IN.localTexcoord.xy - _DrawPosition;
                if (pos.y > 1 || pos.y < 0 || pos.x > 1 || pos.x < 0)
                    return previousColor;
                float4 drawColor = tex2D(_DrawBrush, pos);

                return lerp(previousColor, drawColor, drawColor.a);
            }
```

[image: слева это текстура наложенная с помощью шейдера на custom render texture, а справа спрайт(образец как должно быть)]

Comment: Цель шейдера отобразить кисть на поверхности? Ты думаешь? А как проверял?

Comment: цель шейдера рисовать. Кисть рисует, но текстура кисти не правильно накладывается.